# How can resolve Mixed Content: with Wordpress with HTTPS and can't access to admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, https

I've a server with 3 Wordpress. With one of them, I've changed (add an "s" after http) two URL in **General Settings** Wordpress Adress and Site Adress.

Since I've do that, I'had ERR_TO_MANY_REDIRECT error. So I've add theses lines in my wp-config file :

`define('WP_HOME','http://www.mywebsite.com/wordpress/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.mywebsite.com/wordpress/');`

And now I've an error `Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

A lot of files (like CSS) is not recognised and I'can't access to my wp-admin.

I don't know what to do and I don't understand why the problem is on my 3 wordpress if I had change that in one of them...

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Maybe `define('WP_HOME','https://www.mywebsite.com/wordpress/');` and `define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.mywebsite.com/wordpress/');`? `phpmyadmin` is an interface for mysql interactions, that doesn't seem relevant here

Comment: Theses lines are in my wp-config file, not in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution :

1. Comment my rules for HTTPS in my .htaccess.
2. Access to my wp-admin ( I can access now )
3. Install the plugin SSL Insecure Content Fixer
4. Now I can access to my different Wordpress in HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

When you host a site on secure domain i.e. (https://) you cannot use insecure URL's in your files (http://) so the options with you are you use SSL on other servers as well.

You can try Certbot for installing SSL certificate on your other servers.

Comment: I've a SSL certificate with LetsEncrypt on my server. But my other wordpress are in the same ftp. So, it's ok with one certificate for all my different directory in my ftp no ?

Comment: But like you said, I can't use insecure URL's in my files (http://) but in wordpress files, links are only on http...

Comment: Install SSL certificate on the other servers also

Comment: When you said "servers" you mean "directory" ? Because everything is one server

Comment: If they are on one server you can use them with directory e.g. `https://www.example.com/folder1
https://www.example.com/folder2`
etc.